# Fitness score must be different for all chromosomes?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I have a genetic algorithm and i have to calculate the fitness score for each chromosome. Fitness score must be different for all chromosomes or some of them can have the same?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the same fitness score for all chromsomes in your population.

Imagine testing chromosome 1 on fitness function A, resulting in a high score. Imagine testing chromosome 2 on fitness function B, resulting in a low score. But chromosome 2 scores very high on function A, without you even knowing it.

The goal of a genetic algorithm is to optimize a solution to an objective - this objective should be equal for ALL chromosomes.

**But I think you may have meant this:** yes, it is perfectly feasable that two or more chromosomes share the same score. That means their ancestry is similar.

Comment: *"That means their ancestry is similar."*  no, that means that the objective function cannot distinguish their corresponding phenotype from one another, and thus the evolution is indifferent on the eventual dominance of one over the other, or vice-versa.